# How to do Range Normalization on a specific Layer Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, normalization, multiclass-classification

Below is my model which I am using for multi-class classification

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6, input_dim = input_dim , activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'softmax'))
adam = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer = 'adam' , metrics = ['accuracy'] )
```

I wanted to **Range Normalize** the output produced by the first layer, i.e. layer with relu activation, **between 0 and 1**. 
I have checked Normalization layers available in Keras but as far as I have read they produce the output with mean 0 and stddev 1.

I am not sure what is the procedure for performing custom Normalization on a layer in Keras.

Comment: you can use a sigmoid activation which pushes your output in [0,1]  instead of relu

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a sigmoid function as this will map the output to [0,1], whereas relu maps between (0, inifinity]